# Parsing The Data from Rasberry Pi to Arduino for controlling 8 Relay

Tags: python, c, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-communication

My project Bidirectional Communicate between Arduino and Rasberry Pi for implementing many AC Applications, sofar the read from Arduino to Rasberry Pi has been solved

The only *Problem* now is parsing the data receving from the Rasberry Pi to the Arduino Mega, i have follow others guidance but it seem to be a little stuck, currently i had not used the char Parsing method like [Robin2](https://forum.arduino.cc/u/Robin2) Example 5 from [ [Parsing Serial Data and separating it into variables](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/parsing-serial-data-and-separating-it-into-variables/619949)] But using the String lib SubString method to count the byte for getting the data

In Rasberry Pi i have the code like the below:

```py
# yes i could remove the semicolons, i did that for various method testing
Res = re1 +','+ re2 +','+ re3 +','+ re4 +','+ re5 +','+ re6 +','+ re7 +','+ re8
ser.write(b"Res\n")
```

it will output a series like *re1onn,re2off,re3on....re8off*

Which i have the following code from the Arduino side

```
// all the variable has been defined above
 if (Serial.available()) 
  {
    command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    command.trim();
    if (command.substring(0,8) == "re1onn") {
      digitalWrite(re1, LOW);
    } else if (command.substring(0,8) == "re1off") {
      digitalWrite(re1, HIGH);
    }
    if (command.substring(10,18) == "re2on") {
      digitalWrite(re2, LOW);
    } else if (command.substring(10,18) == "re2off") {
      digitalWrite(re2, HIGH);
    }
```

Can u guys check my method?

Merry Xmas everyone <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may send strings like `11111111`, `01101111`, ... etc. where `1` means `on` and `0` means `off` and their position represents the relay number.

Comment: wow, why didnt i think of that, so should i use the String.charAt() method to get the byte at the exact posiition muhammadyusuf-san? like ```c if (charAt(0) == 1) ``` or which method should i use to parse that data ?

Comment: @Kyle-Toof `[]` allows you access to the individual characters of a `String` (Same as `charAt()`). [ArduinoReference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/operators/elementaccess/) [StringTurorials](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/#strings)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, i have solved the problem. Below are the Bug&Debug for this article

on Thonny (RasbianOS Python IDE) i have make some mistake on the ser.write

```py
res = re1 + re2
ser.write(b"res\n")
```

I have print out "res\n" instead of "10" so i have corrected it

```py
res = re1 + re2 +"\n"
ser.write(res.encode())
```

Then on the  ArduinoIDE below are the debug code for it to receive the Serial command from Rasperry Pi

```
/*Variables define*/
String command;
String command1;
String command2;
```

```
/*Serial receive and on/off function*/
 if (Serial.available()) {
    command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    command.trim();
    // just seperate those 2 String command and we good to go

    // get String at position 0 and 1, which are re1 & re2 from Ras
    command1 = command.charAt(0);
    command2 = command.charAt(1);
    
    // compare the String which we get from above
     if (command1.equals("0")) {
      digitalWrite(Re1, HIGH);
    }
    else if (command1.equals("1")) 
    {
      digitalWrite(Re1, LOW);
    }
    if (command2.equals("0")) {
      digitalWrite(Re2, HIGH);
    }
    else if (command2.equals("1")) 
    {
      digitalWrite(Re2, LOW);
    }
```

Merry Chirstmas everyone <3